# iPhone Simulator running old version of code with iOS 4

Tags: ios4, ios-simulator

I'm having problems with the iPhone Simulator running an out of date version of my app binary with iOS 4, since it seems Xcode is not killing the process completely, hence the debugger is picking up the app process from the previous build/debug cycle, even if I click the "Kill" button on the toolbar.

Does anyone know a way of forcing the simulator to stop and reload the newly compiled version of a binary, other than i) quitting the simulator ii) completely resetting the simulator?  Both of these work arounds are inconvenient and slow down code/build/debug cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed a bug about this (rdar://8247461) and it was marked as a duplicate of rdar://8060328 - this is driving me crazy - I hope it gets fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks Kent - glad to know it's not just me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're nagged by this issue during development, the following is a workaround:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
#if (TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
  abort();
#endif
}
```

Since when you recompile, it will put the app into the background, this will abort the execution. Of course this blocks any multi-tasking-usage in the simulator and should not be used in final builds (since apple doesn't like abort() calls).

Comment: This helps my problem! But not perfect. When the simulator is running my app and I make changes then click Build & Run, my app closes, and the status says `Installing App_Name in Simulator` but nothing happens after that.  I still have to either click the home button before Build & Run. Or I have to hit Build & Run twice for it to work. (my old solution was quitting the simulator every time, so this is a better). Maybe I can have a Script auto-run on build that background's or quits the Simulator. Think that's possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Have a look at OSX AppleScript http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html

Answer (score 1):

how about using **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend** in your plist?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are experiencing the problem, but if you want to delete an app from the simulator click and hold on the app to get the delete to come up. If you can terminate an app in the back ground by double clicking the home button and then clicking and holding on an app. Sorry if none of that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for the reply.  Strange thing is, I never had a problem before iOS4, but I can't quite believe Apple would overlook this problem.  I felt sure I must be missing something obvious?